# HTC One (M8) blinking red notification light

Tags: battery, htc-one-m8

So after replacing the battery in my One (M8) with a new one from eBay, the notification light just blinks orange when charging. When swapping back to the battery before replacement, it, at least, shows a battery charging screen. What am I doing wrong? I've heard something about 'deep discharge' where it needs to be on the flashing light for 15 to 30 minutes to actually start charging or something like that.

Is this new battery a dud? Should I keep charging it? Really don't know what to do at this point...

Update! I reseating the battery connector on the motherboard and now it's a solid red light when plugged in! Hooray! When pressing the power button, though, nothing is shown on the screen. It's still all black. I just now replaced the screen, since I broke the LCD below the glass last time I tried to take it apart.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, but looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great. Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the snap on the bottom of the battery connector is seated properly. Hold your finger on the connector while you set the screws.

Answer (score 0):

Also happened to me. Also reseated the battery but then it still blinked. After a  while when I almost gave up the screen came up all by itself with a battery symbol and it started charging. Then the screen went off and the led turned solid orange. By that time I could also switch it on again normally.